# Event handling on a textbox to load image

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, html, onload-event

After onclick event has happened over a textbox,How can i load a particular image on the webpage? in JavaScript or jquery commands also would do!

**Edit**

```
<script> function try(ob){ 
 ob.<!-- i dont know what to do here --> } 
</script> . . . . 
<td><input type="text" class="inp-form" name="caseid" id="caseid" onclick="try(this)"/>       </td>
```

Comment: Show us the code please?

Comment: can you give us some html to work with at least? it would also be great if we could see how you handled the onclick event, so we could give an answer suited to your code

Comment: <script>
    function try(ob){
        
        ob.<!-- i dont know what to do here -->
    }
    </script>
.
.
.
.
 <td><input type="text" class="inp-form" name="caseid" id="caseid" onclick="try(this)"/></td>

Comment: i am calling a function for onclick for that textbox but i don't know how that passed object has to be handled to get that image displayed anywhere in my webpage

Comment: Do you want to insert a new image tag `<img>` in the markup of your webpage or just want to change the src of a previously added `<img>` tag?

Comment: I wanted to insert a new img tag!Anyway thanks for your concern,i found my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following javascript & html as sample code to view an image on click of 'textbox'-

JavaScript-

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#textbox").click(function(){
    $("#image").show('slow');           
  })    
});
```

html-

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="textbox" /><br />
<img src="images.jpg" id="image" style="display:none;" />
```

It loads 'images.jpg' on click if '#textbox'. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

If you want to load a new image by adding a new `img` tag to your page somewhere, do this:

```
<!-- Your HTML markup -->
<input type="text" id="myTextBox"/>
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- This is where the image will be added --></div>

<!-- Your Javascript : Remember to add Javascript Plugin in your webpage on top-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTextBox").click(function() {
        $("#wrapper").append("<img src='http://www.myfico.com/Images/sample_overlay.gif' alt='sample'></img>");
    });
});
```